# Query documents with array of array in Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I've documents in Cosmos DB with a following structure:

```json
{
  "id": "pst_bf6i9GM0JTN8W1m66N8F",
  "postTitle": "Post 1",
  "memberships": [
      [
          {
              "chain": 1,
              "contractAddress": "0xcB3165Df24BAe1aB590616DE7a950Dd804f39A3C",
              "id": "mbs_IUTG9kJG84Gv2jr17Y8y"
          },
          {
            "chain": 1,
            "contractAddress": "0x00758fc71Cee3AC591E69fF9010c88782E678De2",
            "id": "mbs_jUTG9kJG83Gv2jr17Y8y"
          }
      ],
      [
          {
              "chain": 80001,
              "contractAddress": "0x358738C2Fa36bbb3e983Dc0CC17798E0ef0653f2",
              "id": "mbs_cUTG9kJGx3Gv2jr17Y8l"
          }
      ]
  ]
}
```

The memberships property is an array of array that in the app logic represents the requirements (AND/OR) for getting access to the post protected content (*useless to give more details about that*).

I'd like to write a query that can extract all posts that contains a paired list of `contractAddress` and `chain` values. **How can I do it?**

I tried in many ways, but the only one I was able to implement is creating a Stored Procedure and filter items using code.

To explain better I will write the query in **pseudo-code** (or better not correct code) since I don't how to do it properly (and even if it is possible):

```sql
SELECT c.id FROM c WHERE ARRAY_LENGTH(c.memberships) > 0
AND (ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.memberships, {contractAddress: "0x00758fc71Cee3AC591E69fF9010c88782E678De2", chain: 1}) OR
ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.memberships, {contractAddress: "0x358738C2Fa36bbb3e983Dc0CC17798E0ef0653f2", chain: 80001})
```

The expected output of this query is to extract exactly the document ID of the document presented before:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "pst_bf6i9GM0JTN8W1m66N8F",
  }
]
```

Comment: Please edit to provide a [mcve] - in other words, include both your expected output and actual output, along with the query you tried and issues you're having. Right now it's some sample data, without expected output, and without any attempt. Also: not exactly part of what you're asking, but why an array of arrays? If each sub-array is tied together with a `chain` value, why not have the `chain` property as the identifying property of a subarray just containing `contractAddress` and `id`? I suspect you're making your query much more complex with the current schema.

Comment: Also: I'm assuming you're using the native SQL API (and I added that tag, accordingly). If this is incorrect, please edit the tags.

Comment: what is the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a self-join to get the ability to filter on the sub elements of memberships. Then add a boolean parameter to the `ARRAY_CONTAINS` to do partial matches, since you don't specify the `id` of the membership inside the `ARRAY_CONTAINS`. The self-join will have the side effect that it'll duplicate the result if there's multiple matches for the same document. That can be overcome by a `DISTINCT` in the `SELECT`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT c.id 
FROM c
JOIN m IN c.memberships
WHERE ARRAY_LENGTH(m) > 0
AND (
    ARRAY_CONTAINS(m, {contractAddress: '0x00758fc71Cee3AC591E69fF9010c88782E678De2', chain: 1}, true) 
    OR ARRAY_CONTAINS(m, {contractAddress: '0x358738C2Fa36bbb3e983Dc0CC17798E0ef0653f2', chain: 80001}, true)
)
```